# set the z-index of an openlayers map

Tags: css, openlayers

I have an openlayers map and I try to implement a "lightbox" image gallery , in the same page.

By ""lightbox" image gallery" I mean that the images/arrows/exit button cover the whole screen.

The problem is that openlayers map covers the lightbox gallery (see image).

I have set `z-index` to the map and to the lightbox divs, like so

```
<div id='map_element' style='width: 900px; height: 400px; z-index:1;'> </div>

//and then for lightbox
#imagegal2 img {
 height:85%;    
 z-index:90;    
}
```

And this does not work

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Where is the lightbox coming in the html? z-index only works if the divs are at the same level (ie, both are contained by the same parent) and have position set. So if the map and lightbox have different parent elements, you need to set the z-index on the parents.

Comment: Can you post your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: @brouxhaha Thanks. It worked cross-browser, by just adding `position` to the `map_element` and the `imagegal2 `.

Answer (score 2):

Where is the lightbox coming in the html? `z-index` only works if the divs are at the same level (ie, both are contained by the same parent) and have `position` set. So if the map and lightbox have different parent elements, you need to set the `z-index` on the parents.

*Moved comment to answer, so you can mark as answered.*